# how to make div fixed at a particular scroll level

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make a particular side div fixed at a particular scroll level a perfect example is the "How to format" bar on the right side of stack oveflow ask question page. Just try asking  a question to view. How is it possible ? with css or jquery.

Comment: To fix a div once scroll reaches a certain level, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850271/how-to-make-div-fixed-after-you-scroll-to-that-div#answer-15850380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this tutorial help you. http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/

or

this one

html

```
<div id="header">HEADER</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="left">LEFT</div>
    <div id="right">RIGHT</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
```

js

```
$(function() {
    var $sidebar = $("#right"), 
        $window = $(window),
        rightOffset = $sidebar.offset(),
        rightDelta = $("#footer").offset().top - $("#header").offset().top - $("#header").outerHeight() - $("#right").outerHeight(),
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: Math.max(Math.min($window.scrollTop() - rightOffset.top + topPadding, rightDelta), 0)
            });
    });

});
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/wFDYV/9/) for example 2

you can select base on your needs hope this can help you..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of how to accomplish this, we listen to the `window` `onscroll` event and if `$(window).scrollTop()` is above a certain threshold we add the `.fixed` class to our sidebar, otherwise remove it. The `.fixed` class sets `position:fixed` so that it sticks. Check out the fiddle for a full working example.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/EvAdP/)

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var threshold = 100;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100)
        $('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
    else
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
});
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebar {
    position:absolute;
    width:80px;
    background-color:#0F0;
    height:200px;
}

#sidebar.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<header>
    I'm the header
</header>
<div id="container">
    <aside id="sidebar">
        I'm a sidebar
    </aside>
    <section id="content">
        ...
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var my_scrol_position = 220;
   $("#my_div_name").scrollTop(my_scrol_position);
});
```

make sure that your `div` has `css` with `overflow:auto`