# How to make div fixed after you scroll to that div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, css-position

How to make a `div` remain fixed after you scroll to that `div`? I have a `div` that is later in a page and you need to scroll to get to that `div`.

If I use:

```
.divname {
  position: fixed;
}
```

The `div` will appear before it should appear normally. Maybe a good example of what I need is second ad on [9gag](https://9gag.com/). If your screen resolution is low enough, you won't see that ad after you load the front page, but after you scroll down, you'll see the second ad and it will remain fixed while you scroll down.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

This is now possible with CSS only, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53832799/1482443

---

In case anyone needs jQuery approach, below is the original answer as it was posted years ago:

I know this is tagged html/css only, but you can't do that with css only. Easiest way will be using some jQuery.

```
var fixmeTop = $('.fixme').offset().top;       // get initial position of the element

$(window).scroll(function() {                  // assign scroll event listener

    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // get current position

    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {           // apply position: fixed if you
        $('.fixme').css({                      // scroll to that element or below it
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0',
            left: '0'
        });
    } else {                                   // apply position: static
        $('.fixme').css({                      // if you scroll above it
            position: 'static'
        });
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5n5MA/2/

Comment: usually it is required to wrap this code with $(window).load(function () { ... });
so fixmeTop will have correct value after loading css files

Answer (score 115):

This is possible with CSS3. Just use `position: sticky`, as seen [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sticky_element).

```
position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari & IE */
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

Comment: This should obviously be changed to the best answer.

Comment: This is not thee best answer! This is THE answer... Others are just workarounds. :D

Comment: i wish there was a way to have position absolute while also being sticky?

Comment: @AkinHwan You can do that, but not with CSS only.

Comment: This is not the best answer in all situations or all scenarios.  If the ancestors of this element don't have height set or don't have overflow set, and for whatever reason they can't have height set or overflow unset, then this won't work.  This might be the case if you are adding an element to a complicated pre existing page.  It is ideal if it can be used though.

Answer (score 6):

jquery function is most important

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#stickytypeheader').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                    $('#stickytypeheader').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
                    $('#sticky').css('display', 'block');
            } else {
                    $('#stickytypeheader').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                    $('#sticky').css('display', 'none');
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

Then use JQuery Lib...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now use HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <p>This text is non sticky</p>
    <p>This text is non sticky</p>
    <p>This text is non sticky</p>
    <p>This text is non sticky</p>
 </div>

<div id="stickytypeheader">
 <table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://growthpages.com/">Growth pages</a></td>

    <td><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a></td>

    <td><a href="http://yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a></td>

    <td><a href="http://www.bing.com/">Bing</a></td>

    <td><a href="#">Visitor</a></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>

<div id="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Check [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Jimmy123/Lk8dLwLv/1/)

Answer (score 5):

Adding on to `@Alexandre Aimbiré`'s answer - sometimes you may need to specify `z-index:1` to have the element always on top while scrolling.
Like this:

```
position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari & IE */
position: sticky;
top: 0;
z-index: 1;
```

Comment: You could have just improved his answer or comment

Comment: I could have done that, but I don't have enough reputation points to add a comment or improve others answes.

Comment: Oh sorry about, and so I'll upvote

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
if($(window).width() >= 1200){
    (function($) {
        var element = $('.to_move_content'),
            originalY = element.offset().top;

        // Space between element and top of screen (when scrolling)
        var topMargin = 10;

        // Should probably be set in CSS; but here just for emphasis
        element.css('position', 'relative');

        $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

            element.stop(false, false).animate({
                top: scrollTop < originalY
                    ? 0
                    : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
            }, 0);
        });
    })(jQuery);
}
```

Try this ! just add class .to_move_content to you div

Comment: works like charm! if anyone needs `z-index: 9999` in CSS will bring <div> element in front of other content

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(document).scrollTop(), //get page y value 
        header = $("#myarea"); // your div id
    if(y >= 400)  {
        header.css({position: "fixed", "top" : "0", "left" : "0"});
    } else {
        header.css("position", "static");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is what I needed.