# html - How to make a div element stay at the top while you scroll?

Tags: jquery, html

I have been wanting to know how to make a div element stay at the top of the page while you scroll, like I've seen on some sites. I've seen many solutions but they don't work for me, and i'm not sure why.

So I've been searching on how to do this for quite a while, and the closest I've got was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850271/how-to-make-div-fixed-after-you-scroll-to-that-div), but it seems that something is wrong.
My js is this:

```
var navTop = $('.nav').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll >= navTop) {
        $('.nav').css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0',
            left: '0'
        });
    } else {
        $('.nav').css({
            position: 'static'
        });
    }
});
```

And my html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="scrll.js"></script>
<style>
a:link {
color:#000000; background-color:transparent
}
a:visited {
color:#000000; background-color:transparent
}
a:hover {
color:#000000; background-color:transparent
}
a:active {
color:#000000; background-color:transparent
}
body {
    height: 3000px;
}
#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888888;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.fixme {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;    
    border-radius: 25px;
}
#section {
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;        
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
<h1 style="font-size: 400%">Website</h1>
</div>

<div class="nav">
<a href="home.html" style="text-decoration:none"> Home |</a>
<a href="download.html" style="text-decoration:none"> Activity |</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com/" style="text-decoration:none" target="_blank"> Google |</a>
<a href="suggestions.html" style="text-decoration:none"> Suggestions |</a>
</div>

<div id="section">
<h2>Suggestions</h2>
<p>
Herpdaderp
</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It works in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5n5MA/2/), but it doesn't seems to work externally on my computer. I've even tried pasting the code directly and making it into its own html document, but even that dosent work.

I believe that it has something to do with the html using the javascript, but I may be wrong. Does anyone have some help with this?

Comment: did you get anything in the console ( F12 ) strange that the fiddle is working and none on your comp

Comment: I don't see that you included _jQuery_  in your html code. Without that it won't work.

Comment: @t.niese I included it externally from the <script>, but I also tried it with the _jQuery_ in the code itself and it still didnt work... May be something with my computer

Comment: How does the line look like where you include the `jQuery` library?

Comment: @t.niese <script src="scrll.js"></script>, but I think it is the "$ is not defined problem".

Comment: This is your scrolling code, but not jQuery itself. jQuery is a library you need to include. You can download it from the [jQuery website](http://jquery.com/) or include it using their [CDN](http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-39-s-cdn-provided-by-maxcdn) (and you need to include it before you scrolling code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **.fixme** to **.nav** in your CSS.

And add this before you close the **body tag**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function(){
            //Gives you the distance from top of document to the element
            //no what you can see, think of it as if you print the page
            //and then measure the distance from the top to the nav...
            var navOffsetTop = $('.nav').offset().top;
            //Add a listener for the scroll movement
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                //Gives you how much pixels has moved the scrollbar
                var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                //If the distance puts you in the nav position
                if (currentScroll >= navOffsetTop) {
                    //Change the nav to be fixed in the page
                    $('.nav').css({
                        position: 'fixed',
                        top: '0',
                        left: '0'
                    });
                } else {
                    //Returns the nav to no-fixed position
                    $('.nav').css({
                        position: 'static'
                    });
                }
            });     
        }); 
    </script>
```

See:

```
<html>
    <head>        
      <style type="text/css">
        a:link {
        color:#000000; background-color:transparent
        }
        a:visited {
        color:#000000; background-color:transparent
        }
        a:hover {
        color:#000000; background-color:transparent
        }
        a:active {
        color:#000000; background-color:transparent
        }
        #header {
            background-color:black;
            color:white;
            text-align:center;
            padding:5px;
            box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888888;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
        .nav {
            line-height:30px;
            background-color:#eeeeee;
            height:30px;
            width:100%;
            float:left;
            padding:5px;    
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
        #section {
            width:350px;
            float:left;
            padding:10px;        
        }
        body {
            height: 3000px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="header">
        <h1 style="font-size: 400%">Website</h1>
      </div>

        <div class="nav">
            <a href="home.html" style="text-decoration:none"> Home |</a>
            <a href="download.html" style="text-decoration:none"> Activity |</a>
            <a href="https://www.google.com/" style="text-decoration:none" target="_blank"> Google |</a>
            <a href="suggestions.html" style="text-decoration:none"> Suggestions |</a>
        </div>

        <div id="section">
            <h2>Suggestions</h2>
            <p>
                Herpdaderp
            </p>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                var navOffsetTop = $('.nav').offset().top;

                $(window).scroll(function() {
                    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                    if (currentScroll >= navOffsetTop) {
                        $('.nav').css({
                            position: 'fixed',
                            top: '0',
                            left: '0'
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('.nav').css({
                            position: 'static'
                        });
                    }
                });     
            }); 
        </script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

In my case only put the effect in the nav element:

http://jsfiddle.net/abrhmcc/vc6bhL1o/2/

But if you don't want to use jQuery, and always have the header and nav on top, just set this in the css for the header and the nav:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index:2;
```

Just change the distance from the top to your convenience.

And set margin to your section:

```
margin-top: 200px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abrhmcc/vc6bhL1o/4/

Comment: Thx! This stuff is kind of confusing to me considering that I just got into it. Im gonna learn javascript hopefully, if im not lazy.