# lock a div on header when window scrolled past element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a circle div to lock in the header when the user scrolls past in.

I'm using the following code but it doesn't work

```
var circle$ = $('.circle'),
    oCircleBottom = circle$.offset().top + circle$.outerHeight(true),
    window$ = $(window);

window$.scroll(function() {
    if (window$.scrollTop() > oCircleBottom) {

    }
}.bind(this));
```

I want to perform an action when the user scrolls pass the circle div; however, the code above does not seem to work. Is oCircleBottom computed correctly?

Comment: [Check this on how to make div fixed after scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850271/how-to-make-div-fixed-after-you-scroll-to-that-div)

Comment: I need how to scroll past the div

Comment: What do you mean by scroll past? Can you explain? your question says `I want a circle div to lock in the header when the user scrolls past in.` or rather, what action you `want` to perform when user scrolls past it?

Comment: I'm saying that   `oCircleBottom = circle$.offset().top + circle$.outerHeight(true),` doesn't tell me if someone scrolls past the circle div

Comment: Is this what you looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/s6sdy9r1/

Comment: Why did you substract the window.innerHeight?

Comment: I added explanation with an example as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your code in $(document).ready function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var circle$ = $('.circle'),
    oCircleBottom = circle$.offset().top + circle$.outerHeight(true),
    window$ = $(window);

    window$.scroll(function () {
    if (window$.scrollTop() > oCircleBottom) {
        $('.circle').css({                      
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0',
            left: '0'
        });
    } 
    else{
               $('.circle').css({                      
                position: 'static'});
    }
  }.bind(this));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take window height into account because if the height of the page isnt enough to scroll down, your code doesnt work. Take a look at [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/s6sdy9r1/4/)

However, if the increase page height, you code will work fine without subtracting window height.  Take a look at [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/s6sdy9r1/5/)

Hence, its better to subtract the window height. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6sdy9r1/)

```
  $(window).bind('scroll', function() {

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.circle').offset().top + $('.circle').innerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
       //Do you stuff
    }
});
```