# Fixed div is not detecting where I am on page when I'm scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've looked at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850271/how-to-make-div-fixed-after-you-scroll-to-that-div) and followed the top answer but I can't get it to work for me.

**HTML**

```
<div id="project">
   <div class="details">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum>
   </div>
   <div class="process">
      <div class="col-6 fixme">Content</div>
      <div class="col-6">Content</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#project {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:100%;
}
body.projectLoaded #project {
    opacity:1;
    top:0;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var fixmeTop = $('.fixme').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
            $('.fixme').css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '0',
                left: '0'
            });
        } else {
            $('.fixme').css({
                position: 'static'
            });
        }
    });
```

I've a better understanding of the issue and why I got it working in a fiddle but not [here](http://darrenbachan.com/#/dayton2daytona). When on the homepage, if I'm scrolling down, after x height it becomes fixed. Once `.projectLoaded` is on body a fixed div `#project` is present, in the fixed div I'm trying to make it so when you scroll to `.fixme` it also becomes fixed, but it doesn't detect that you're at the right point in the scroll for the div to become fixed.

Is something like $(window, "#project-container").scroll(function() realistic?

Also, this is sort of a side question, but if it becomes fixed, how can I contain it in a relative div? Would it look like this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container { position:relative; width:1280px; }
.parent { position:absolute; }
.child { position:fixed; width:960px; }
```

Would this be the best approach? What I want to achieve is when you look at this [page](http://darrenbachan.com/#/dayton2daytona), I'd like the `.fixme` div to follow the user as you scroll down.

Comment: `position:fixed;top:100%;` means you are telling the div to stay below the rectangle of the viewport at all times.

Comment: When the project is clicked on, a class is added so top is 0. It's visible and is above the page below, but this is the issue. Because of this I can't get the window to recognize where the .fixme div is.

Answer (score 1):

Do this with jQuery

```
function fixDiv() {
    var $div = $(".fixme");
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top")) { 
        $div.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'width': '100%'}); 
    }
    else {
        $div.css({'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto', 'width': '100%'});
    }
}

$('.fixme').data("top", $('.fixme').offset().top); // set original position on load
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bx8cqg8e/4/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {                           //makes sure document is loaded

        var fixmeTop = $('.yourdiv').offset().top; //gets the initial position of element
          $(window).scroll(function() {           //scroll event listener
            var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); //applies position, and makes it fixed when you scroll to it or below ↓
            if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {          
              $('.yourdiv').css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '0',
                left: '0'
            });
            } else {
              $('.yourdiv').css({  //sets position to static if you scroll above it ↑
                position: 'static'
            });
          }
        });
      });
```

Comment: Sorry about that, added some comments. Hope it helps!