# 2 panel layout with fixed right panel after some scroll with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble in creating a layout where there are two panels with left panel having a relative positioning and right panel fixed only after a specific scroll. Also, I need to have its height adjusted if the page scroll reaches bottom to not overlap right panel on footer section.

[image: design]

So far I have done [this](https://jsfiddle.net/we84m2zn/5/), but it breaks coz of its height calculation when the content refreshes on the right hand side or if the left panel has lesser content compared to the right panel.

jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).on('scroll',function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop() > 120) {
     $('.panelright').addClass('fixedpanel');
      
      
    }
     else
      $('.panelright').removeClass('fixedpanel');
  });
});
```

```css
header{
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
footer {
  height:50px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  clear:both;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.panelleft, .panelright {
  width: 45%;
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.fixedpanel {
  position:fixed;
  right:0px;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 60px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <header></header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panelleft">
      
      <p>
      Lrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="panelright">
      <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

There are couple of things m trying to do here for which i dont have a working code but only the fiddle i have shared above.

1. To set the right panel to fixed positioning after it reaches the container it is in or after a specific scroll.
2. To update its height when it reaches bottom so that it doesnt overlap footer.
3. To only set its position fixed if the left panel is bigger then the viewport. In this case set the height of right panel same as left panel irrespective of the content in it and set its overflow css property to auto.

Really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850271/how-to-make-div-fixed-after-you-scroll-to-that-div

Comment: @P.Iakovakis my query is totally different then that post. I am trying to make a right panel fixed after scroll and not a nav bar. Also the issue m having is adjusting its height based on the left panel and when it reaches bottom of page.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
.panelleft, .panelright{
   margin-bottom:10px;
```

}
Using this your grid section don't overlap with footer. For now I just solve overlap issue with footer.
See you can apply height on page scroll but I don't think it is a right solution .. 
If you have still any query please comment I will try to shortout

Comment: thanks for the update. I have already applied bottom margin to 10px when the page has not reached end of scroll and once it reaches end, i apply the 60px one. My main issue here is, it is not working when i have lesser content in the left panel.

Comment: Thanks mate :)
For that you can make some changes in css 
.fixedpanel{
bottom :auto;
height : 70px; 
}
/*here You can add dynamic height according to the content on page scroll*/

Comment: yea that is still not an issue. My issue is with setting it to fixed position only when the left panel is bigger than the viewport/user visible area.

Comment: You mean that you want to apply fixed position on right section when left panel is bigger than user visible area ? Sorry but I am unable to understand your question properly :P

Comment: yea. Please check the fiddle. Try to scroll and you will see it breaks, sort of gets confused weather to stay fixed or relative..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148198/discussion-between-abhijeet-and-narcs).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make `panelright` `fixed` only when user scrolls more than `120px` and also only when `panelleft` is bigger than `viewport` you need to add another condition to the `if`

see below or [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4ed5afex/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 120 && $(this).height() < $('.panelleft').height()) {
      $('.panelright').addClass('fixedpanel');

    } else {
      $('.panelright').removeClass('fixedpanel');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
header {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.panelleft,
.panelright {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.fixedpanel {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 60px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <header></header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panelleft">

      <p>
        Lrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
        passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
        remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="panelright">
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```