# Trying to sticky a video in Squarespace? Is this possible?

Tags: css, sticky, squarespace

I'm simply trying to emulate one of these methods for stickying a video that will play as a viewer reads a blog post on my Squarespace site.

https://www.cssigniter.com/make-sticky-floating-videos-page-scroll/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning

[How to make div fixed after you scroll to that div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850271/how-to-make-div-fixed-after-you-scroll-to-that-div)

http://js fiddle.net/4mqLhnpf/

Preferably the video would lock to the top portion of the screen, allowing the article to be scrolled below it.

I've tried all methods listed above and none have worked. I've copied the code directly, and even changed IDs and classes in case something was overlapping and causing an error. Nothing works. Is this sort of functionality not allowed by Squarespace inherently or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the CSS `position` property. 
Simply add this to the `div` styling:

```
position: sticky;
position: -webkit-sticky;
top: 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, however I inserted this style inline and nothing happened. The background turns red, so the code is being read, and there is no error upon inspection in Chrome.

<div style="position: sticky; position: -webkit-sticky; top: 0; background: red;">content</div>

Comment: Do you mind sending the source code of and around the div content and the styling?

Comment: Also, what browser are you using? And where exactly is the initial position of your video?