# Onscroll follow to some point

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I have a scrolltofixed above the footer which needs to be hide after scrolling to some point. i ready have two sticky bars as header and one at middle my third sticky bar is scrolling till the second. So, whenever my second sticky bar goes and sticks at the first my third bar should stop there. please if anyone can help me will be appreciated

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.sub-navbar2').scrollToFixed( {
      bottom: 0,
      limit: function() {
          var limit = $('.footer-v2').offset().top - $('.sub-navbar2').outerHeight(true) - 10;
          return limit;
      },
      minWidth: 320,
      zIndex: 999,
      fixed: function() {  },
      dontCheckForPositionFixedSupport: true
    });
});
```

Comment: not sure if it would help you want to scroll until https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850271/how-to-make-div-fixed-after-you-scroll-to-that-div ?