# How to make div switch to bottom fixed after you scroll to that div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Good day everyone. I am trying to switch my div into a fixed one at the bottom when it appears on screen when both scrolling up and down.

I found this stack overflow topic which does the thing I'm attepting to do but at top [HERE.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850271/how-to-make-div-fixed-after-you-scroll-to-that-div)

Code:

```
var fixmeTop = $('.fixme').offset().top;       // get initial position of the element

$(window).scroll(function() {                  // assign scroll event listener

    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // get current position

    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {           // apply position: fixed if you
        $('.fixme').css({                      // scroll to that element or below it
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0',
            left: '0'
        });
    } else {                                   // apply position: static
        $('.fixme').css({                      // if you scroll above it
            position: 'static'
        });
    }

});
```

After many try and many articles red, I just can't manage to tweak it to be fixed at the bottom (kind of new to javascript). So I am please asking for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can do it like this

```js
const heightOfText = 15
if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop - $(window).height() + heightOfText) {
   $('.fixme').css({
       position: 'fixed',
       bottom: '0',
       left: '0'
   });
}
```

So when you see your `.fixme` at the bottom of the text it attaches to the bottom with `bottom: '0'`. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
Like this ?

jQuery(function($){
var fixmeTop = $('.fixme').offset().top;       

$(window).scroll(function() {                  

    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 

  const heightOfText = 15
if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop - $(window).height() + heightOfText) {
   $('.fixme').css({
       position: 'fixed',
       bottom: '0',
       left: '0'
   });
}
    } else {                                   
        $('.fixme').css({                     
            position: 'relative'
        });
    }
});
});

Comment: @JoevinGracien it is a bit hard to read but seems right, but that would only stick if you scroll down, I guess it can be adjusted a bit to behave the same way when you scroll up, but it is only when you use Jquery, I think @Roko C. Buljan answered better, I would just use `position: sticky`, is there a specific reason you need to use Jquery?

Comment: Thank you again!
Either it's not working or I can't make it right. I am going to try the Roko C. Buljan way.

No actual specific reason but I am failing with both css and JS so far.

Comment: Here is codepen of my solution https://codepen.io/Skith/pen/XWXgVpe?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position: sticky`

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}

.content {
  min-height: 200vh;
  border: 4px dashed #000;
}

.sticky-bottom {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 2em 0;
  background: #0bf;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="content">
    1. Lorem ut florem...
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="content">
    2. Lorem ut florem...
  </div>
  <div class="sticky-bottom">Stick me when in viewport</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! @Roko C. Buljan

For some reason, this only seems to work when I'm scrolling back to the top but not when scrolling all the way down (the div sticks to the top and not the bottom)

Comment: @JoevinGracien have you run my example demo? have you tried to remove the last group of elements? (PS: You're welcome!)

Comment: Yes I did, but I couldn't make it work for some reason (It might be related to the Wordpress Theme/Builder I'm using). 
I will go deeper into that way next time since @Evgeny Klimenchenko's solution is working and I had enough of it for today to be honest haha.
Thank you very much for your time nonetheless !

Comment: @JoevinGracien no worries, happy coding.