# Scroll-then-fix css grid column in ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, position, css-grid

I have below structure of CSS Grid in ReactJS in which I have three columns in a row.

```
<div class="Container">
                <div class="Layout">
                    <Leftside />
                    <Main />
                    <Rightside />
                </div>
                
            </div>
```

The styling of `container` and `Layout` is given below:

```
.Container{
    padding-top: 50px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.Layout{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(0,3fr) minmax(0,6fr) minmax(0,3fr);
    margin: 10px 0;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

I have below structure on the browser:
[image]

What I want is that the 3rd column(Add to your feed) scrolls along with the page for some time(There is a gap of 50px between this column and navbar) until it gets to the top and then it should remain fixed there. I applied following styles to the rightside column:

```
function Rightside=(props)=>{
return(
<Container>
  //Other code
   </Container>);
}

const Container = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
`;
```

But what is happening is that even after page is scrolled, it maintains a gap of 50px with the top, which I do not want.

Please help me to write correct css so as to achieve correct rendering.
Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have given `top: 50px;` on your `Container` component.

That tells the 3rd column, that the top most point of the `Container` can be at `50px` only and nothing less than that.

```
function Rightside=(props)=>{
    return(
        <Container>
        //Other code
        </Container>
    );
}

const Container = styled.div`
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0;
`;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what I am looking for is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850271/how-to-make-div-fixed-after-you-scroll-to-that-div). I ahve asked a new question because I think implementing this thing would be a bit different in css grid layout. Also I am using Reactjs so I don't wanna use jQuery.

Comment: Hi There. I have updated the answer. You should be using `position: 'sticky'` if you want the element to be fixed after scrolling. Does that not fix it ?

Comment: No. Position: sticky has no effect. Position: fixed is actually working but not in the desired way.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example. I will try to fix it.